# Images Uploaded in CMS not showing on mobile [desktop is fine]

Tags: image

Just want uploaded images for entries to show for desktop AND mobile

```
{% set assets = entry.galleryImage %}

{% if assets | length %}

{% for asset in assets %}
    {% if asset.kind == 'video' %}
        <video class="vid" preload="none" controls="false" loop webkit-playsinline muted>
            <source src="{{ asset.url }}" poster="{{ asset.url }}" type="video/mp4">
        </video>
    {% else %}
        <img class="gallery_img_1"  src="{{ asset.url }}">
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 2):

From Craft's POV, there's no difference between desktop and mobile.  I'd check your CSS to see if you're changing how things are displayed depending on the `@media` query breakpoints.

Comment: i commented out the style sheet and still nothing :(